# Op amp capacitor value question

Tags: operational-amplifier

Let's have a look at this photo:

[image: preamp]

It shows a simple preamp with C1 capacitor placed to avoid amplifying DC voltage (the loop closed for AC and open for DC). Unfortunately this capacitor limits the bandwidth and cuts off low frequencies. The higher the value of C1 is, the lower loss in bandwidth is achieved (and i don't want to lose bandwidth). So... I saw many circuits with 220 µF cap as C1 but not higher. Spice simulation shows, that rising the value to say 1000 µF visibly widens the bandwidth. Are there any negative consequences of rising the value of C1?

Comment: How much is "visibly" and what cutoff frequency are you getting even with the lower value?  Most people seem to like a lot of bass in their music, but more bass doesn't do you any good if the speaker can't reproduce it and your ears can't hear it.  Going from 300Hz to 100Hz is probably a big win.  Going from 40Hz to 20Hz probably won't be much of an improvement given typical speakers and ears.

Comment: What frequency do you want to go down to?  The values you have will go down to <20Hz.  The microphone is already dropping off at that frequency so you will not gain much by changing the capacitor.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion. I know what i need and that's why i'm asking this question.

Comment: How about telling us what you need so we can help answer your question?

Comment: observe neg. bar polarity

Comment: So, are you saying you need low frequency response below 20 Hz? Could you please tell us why?

Answer (score 3):

You can use any value you want.

A larger value will extend the low frequency bandwidth, however it will also  make power-on settling longer.

At power on, this cap needs to charge to its DC operating point. This takes longer for a larger cap, so you will get a larger and longer turn-on thump.

"Longer" can be... pretty long (check comments below).

Same remarks apply for output cap C4.

Comment: With 1000 uF, the op-amps going to spend the first minute or so after power on with its output up against the upper rail, making the microphone unusable.

Comment: Yep. It's the turn-on thump from hell. Then again, I wonder why the OP thinks he needs a 0.04Hz cutoff on a microphone...

Comment: you might not want to use "any" value , rather use the one given, unless there is good reason otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the value of the capacitor by itself, but the time constant, the RC product, you need to be concerned with.

Here, C1 works with R3, and they have a time constant of 8.6mS = 116 rad/s = 18.5Hz. The response is 3dB down by 18.5Hz, and only 1dB down by twice that at 37Hz.

Those figures would be fine for most people, but maybe doubling the C value would be perceptible by some, if you had really good speakers and some bassy source material.

Do bear in mind that the amplifier is unusable for many time constants following switch-on, while the capacitor charges. Generally, you want the smallest time constant you can use without compromising the frequency response, going way higher is counterproductive.

A more pressing concern is the value of C4, because this forms its time constant with the load, and you haven't defined the load. C4 and the load will have the same time constant as C1.R3 when the load is about 2k.

Assuming this mike preamp is driving an audio input to an amplifier or mixer, it's likely to be in the 10k to 100k range, which is just fine. If you try to drive a 600ohm loads (sometimes found in audio) you'll lose a little bit of bass, and 32ohm headphones will lose a lot.

Answer (score 0):

With this handy chart you can see the impedance of this 2u2 cap has a breakpoint with 3k9 around 20Hz. How low do  you wanna go??

[image]

DC response time is about 1/f after turn on. (pop)

20Hz is perfect.